# MySQL JOIN and select one from two possible sources

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So I would like to join such source

```
SELECT p.subject, p.icon, t.icon AS threadicon, i.path FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN threads t ON (t.id=p.tid)
LEFT JOIN icons i ON (i.id=p.icon OR i.id=t.icon)
```

The problem is, when both post and thread has an icon set it returns a duplicate of post but with two icons. What I would like to achieve is to get icon's path if it is set in post, if there's no such icon as set in post, get icon from thread and if there's no such icon as in thread, return null.

I know it can be done with lots of IFs, but I assume there's something simpler than that.

Comment: I think it worked by using _ON (i.id=coalesce(p.icon,t.icon))_ thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use two `left join`s for this:

```
SELECT p.subject,
       COALESCE(ip.icon, it.icon) AS icon,
       COALESCE(ip.path, it.path) as path
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN
     threads t
     ON t.id = p.tid LEFT JOIN
     icons ip
     ON ip.id = p.icon LEFT JOIN
     icons it
     ON it.id = t.icon;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the icons on the join and only match one of them

```
SELECT p.subject, p.icon, t.icon AS threadicon, i.path
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN threads t ON (t.id=p.tid)
LEFT JOIN icons i ON (i.id=COALESCE(p.icon, t.icon))
```